# Show different block with storeCode

Tags: topmenu, dynamic-blocks

I have this code for my horizontal menu and would like to show different blocks for the different storeViews.

For example the StoreCode is EN i would like to show the block en-horzizontal-menu
the StoreCode is DE i would like to show the block de-horzizontal-menu

The blocks allready exist.

```
<div class="horizontal-menu navigation">
<ul class="smartmenu magebig-nav">
    <li class="level0 level-top mega_"><a class="level-top" href="/superbuy"><span>SuperBuy</span></a></li>
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu; ?>
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
</ul>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
                 ->setBlockId('horizontal-menu') 
                ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.
David

Comment: you can achieve this by getting store id of specific store and add condition on the store base. e.g: if ( store is ==  eng){echo horizontal-en} else { echo horizontal-de}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento is allowed to create CMS blocks for specified store views with the same identifier.

Just go to the admin panel and create two blocks with the identifier "horizontal-menu", the first for the DE store view, the second for the EN store view and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SERVISTO if I helped, please mark my answer as correct. Thx. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create 2 CMS blocks and having the exact same identifier for both store view (e.g. `horizontal-menu`). to call it from phtml, you can try to use this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$getBlockByIdentifier = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Cms\Api\GetBlockByIdentifierInterface::class);
$storeManager = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::class);
$storeId = $storeManager->getStore()->getId();
try {
    $content = $getBlockByIdentifier->execute('homepages', $storeId)->getContent();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $content = '';
}
```

> disclaimer: Object Manager is NOT recommended, so please to convert
> this to use ViewModel or inject it to the block class.